# Как на Angular 2 можно отследить что приложение запускается на телефоне?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Как можно с помощью Angular 2 отследить, что пользователь зашел с телефона в систему (ответы, основанные на отслеживании разрешения экрана не подходят)? Или может есть готовые директивы и модули?

Comment: Подозреваю, что точно так же, как и без ангуляра...

Comment: я имел ввиду - есть ли какие либо готовые решения для этого.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри на [эту](https://github.com/KoderLabs/ng2-device-detector) библиотеку. Она определяет на основе заголовка user agent информацию о ОС(windows, anrdoid...), браузере и т.д.

> An Angular 2 (and beyond) powered AOT compatible device detector that helps to identify browser, os and other useful information regarding the device using the app. The processing is based on user-agent.

**UPDATE**

Следует учитывать, что:

- Заголовок [user-agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) можно программно заменить:

> Forbidden header name:    no

- Есть много [нюансов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent), которые нужно учитывать.

Comment: Только надо предупредить что user agent подменяем очень легко и более-менее устойчивый детект делается по фичам

Comment: Спасибо, внес соответствующие правки в ответ